# Custom calculated aggregated field in Crossfilter

Tags: javascript, json, crossfilter

I have been playing with **crossfilter** and found it great but hit into a wall recently. I don't know if my problem needs **crossfilter** at all, so happy to hear any alternatives solutions.

My data looks like this:

```
[{ 
year: "1987", 
country: "UK", 
product: "pineapple", 
tons_available: 10, 
tons_sold: 8
},
{ year: "1987", country: "US", product: "pineapple", tons_available: 34, tons_sold: 18},
{ year: "1987", country: "UK", product: "pear", tons_available: 4, tons_sold: 3},
{ year: "1987", country: "US", product: "pear", tons_available: 23, tons_sold: 20},
{ year: "1988", country: "UK", product: "pineapple", tons_available: 12, tons_sold: 3},
{ year: "1988", country: "US", product: "pineapple", tons_available: 56, tons_sold: 6},
{ year: "1988", country: "UK", product: "pear", tons_available: 32, tons_sold: 32},
{ year: "1988", country: "US", product: "pear", tons_available: 31, tons_sold: 8},
and on, and on...]
```

I want to aggregate yearly data and was able to do it for metrics already available like "tons_available" and "tons_sold".

```
var by_week = data_to_filter.dimension( function(d) { return d.year; });
var tons_sold_by_week = by_week.group()
                         .reduceSum(function(d) { return d.tons_sold; });
```

However, I cannot find a way to create metrics on top of the aggregated object. For example, I would like to create a *sell-through-rate per year*. For this, I would need to sum all the field per year and then only divide: tons_sold/tons_available.

This ideally would give me a json formatted as:

```
[{ 
year: "1987", 
tons_available: 71, 
tons_sold: 49
str: 0.69
},
{ year: "1988", tons_available: 131, tons_sold: 49, str: 0.37 },
and on, and on...]
```

It seems to me that the aggregated object only keep the summed variables and result with just one couple key/value per year.

Is there way to achieve what I am after?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is still useful to you.

You can do this by defining reduceAdd, reduceRemove and reduceInitial functions for your specific use case and then passing them to reduce.

Code:

```
var cf   = crossfilter(data),
    year = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.year; });

var reduceAdd = function(p, v) {
    p.tons_available += v.tons_available;
    p.tons_sold      += v.tons_sold;
    p.str            = p.tons_sold/p.tons_available;
    return p;
}

var reduceRemove = function(p, v) {
    p.tons_available -= v.tons_available;
    p.tons_sold      -= v.tons_sold;
    p.str            = p.tons_sold/p.tons_available;
    return p;
}

var reduceInitial = function() {
    return {
        tons_available : 0,
        tons_sold      : 0,
        str            : 0
    }
}

var json = year.group().reduce(reduceAdd,reduceRemove,reduceInitial).orderNatural().top(Infinity);

console.log(json);
```

When Crossfilter adds records it uses reduceAdd to recalculate values. When Crossfilter removes filters out records it uses reduceRemove to update values. It needs an initial value which is supplied by reduceInitial (note that it's a function). See this permalink from the docs https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_reduce.

I used the input that you gave above and this is the json that I got as a result:

```
[{key: "1988", value: {
    str: 0.37404580152671757,
    tons_available: 131,
    tons_sold: 49},
 {key: "1987", value: {
    str: 0.6901408450704225,
    tons_available: 71,
    tons_sold: 49}]
```

It's not exactly the output you asked for, but it's pretty close.